# How to set to default to json instead of xml in jersey?

Tags: java, jersey

Using jersey jersey.java.net How do I set JSON as the default serialization instead of XML when there is no accept header or .xml suffix is in the URI?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can assign the quality index to each media type in @Produces annotation. I.e.you can do the following to make Jersey prefer JSON if both XML and JSON are allowed:

```
@Produces({"application/json;qs=1", "application/xml;qs=.5"})
```

Comment: So with the web method capable of producing two media types, how does the requester specify which one it wants? Is it done via a query param? How?

Comment: Using the Accept request header. (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html#z3)

Comment: Not working for me..I am using jersey 2.15.Service is returning XML by default...Any idea?

Comment: @Anand I found that the overall class one didn't work, whether its our implementation I don't know. The one I wanted to deprioritise I put a qs marker on the method. This worked for me. I do know there is a bug in and around 2.16, so maybe upgrading to a later version may help. (old comment I know, for anyones future reference).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set the `@Produces` annotation to specify the return format like so:

```
@Produces( { "application/json" })
```

How come there is no accepts header?

Comment: This will result in a 406 error whenever XML is requested.  The OP wants to be able to return XML and JSON, but default to JSON if neither is requested.

Comment: you mean @Consumes( { "application/json" })

Answer (score -3):

You can specify preference of generation by specifying media types in your order of preference in the @Produces annotation.

```
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
```

In the above code since "application/json" comes first, if no accept header is specified in the request Jersey will default to generating JSON response.

Using qs (as suggested by Martin) makes the preference more explicit, but its a bit more complicated to understand.

Comment: This does not appear to work in the current version.  I cannot speak for older versions of Jersey.   Without the 'accept' header, even if JSON is the first in the Produces list, still returns XML.   Could there be something else that affects this besides the version of Jersey?

Comment: This is just incorrect information. The order of the media types in the Produces annotation has absolutely no effect on the default response.

Comment: Well, Oracle says the order is relevant: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/6nmq2cp2c/index.html But I think it is actually implementation-dependent