# Jersey / Jackson Unsupported Media Type (for XML requests)

Tags: json, xml, rest, jackson, jersey

I have spent two days on this with no luck. I have a project that uses jersey and jackson. It was working fine with JSON requests and tried to add XML also, after adding a couple of jars, it worked also with XML.

The problem was that for requests with no parameters (neither JSON nor XML), the API was retrieving XML instead JSON (we want JSON by default).

My code for requests looks like this:

```
@POST
@Produces({"application/json", "application/xml"})
@Consumes({"application/json", "application/xml"})
public TokenResponse authenticateUser(Credentials credentials) {//code here}
```

In another post a saw that this is a Jetty bug that is resolved in version 2.16, so I decided to migrate to 2.51.1 with no luck. The JSON request works fine, but when I send the xml post (with postman) the server returns an "Unsupported Media Type" error.

I have also tried with version jersey 2.17 because it works with the same jackson libraries than 2.7 and the result is the same than before.

I am not using maven so here it is a copy of the libraries I have used for the three cases:

[image]

1.- JSON and XML works but XML is always returned by default:
2.- JSON works but XML requests returns Unsupported Media Type
3.- JSON works but XML requests returns Unsupported Media Type

Thank you in advance

Finally, instead of updating the libraries I have decided to use the version I had already and add the solution below to @Produces annotation

[How to set to default to json instead of xml in jersey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649259/how-to-set-to-default-to-json-instead-of-xml-in-jersey)

Answer (score 0):

Setting a `qs` factor to each media type as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7655983/1426227) should work. It can take values between `0` (undesirable) and `1` (highly desirable):

```java
@Produces({ "application/json; qs=1", "application/xml; qs=.5" })
```

---

If you don't want to change every single `@Produces` annotation, you can use a filter to add the `Accept: application/json` header if it's not present.

```java
@Provider
@PreMatching
public class DefaultAcceptHeaderFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

        MultivaluedMap<String, String> headers = requestContext.getHeaders();
        if (!headers.containsKey(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT)) {
            headers.putSingle(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        }
    }
}
```

It will ensure that your resource methods will produce JSON even when the `Accept` header is not sent by the client.